# Multiple ECS Operator calls in loop in dag - only 1st one completes

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to run multiple ECS Operator tasks in the same dag, in a loop. I am able to do this successfully using Python operators. I find that only the 1st one gets invoked and the rest get removed. Do you know why ? Can only one ECS operator run in a single job ?

The code looks like this :

```
      start_date=datetime(2021,1,1), 
      schedule_interval='0 20 * * *',   # Run at 20:00 UTC = 15:00 EST
      default_args=default_args,
      catchup=False,
      max_active_runs=10,
      tags=["tag1", "tag2"]
      )

with dag as dag:

  for run_name in ALL_RUNS:

    op_task_run = ECSOperator (
        task_id = f"ecs_{run_name}",
        dag=dag,
        cluster=cluster_name,
        task_definition=task_definition,
        launch_type="FARGATE",
        overrides={
            "containerOverrides": [
                {
                    "name": "ecs_task",
                    "command": [
                                 "python",
                                 "-m","module1.submodule.prog",
                                 "-c", f"configfile",
                                 "-f", f"{run_name}",
                                 "-d",f"{run_date}"
                               ],
                    "environment": [
                    {
                    "name": "ENVIRONMENT", 
                    "value": env
                    },
                    
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        network_configuration=network_configuration,
        awslogs_group=awslogs_group,
        awslogs_stream_prefix=awslogs_stream_prefix,
        propagate_tags="TASK_DEFINITION",
        )
    
    tasks.append(op_task_run)

tasks[0] >> tasks[1] >> tasks[2] >> tasks[3] >> tasks[4]
```

Comment: where is the value of name : task_id = f"ecs_run_{name}") in the loop ? should it be run_name ?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably about indentation. You only have tasks[0] but you are trying to call 5 list items.
Try this:

```
    tasks.append(op_task_run)

  tasks[0] >> tasks[1] >> tasks[2] >> tasks[3] >> tasks[4]
```

Comment: Sorry, I just pasted it wrong. I've fixed it.

Comment: You may also want to paste the complete code and how the dag currently looks like so we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Turns out it was indentation after all, thx. I needed to ensure that the last line to call the tasks was within the `with dag as dag` scope.